# How to reconstruct html file at consumer side in kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, serialization, ioutils

If i feed html files in the form of Array[Byte] at  producer side in kafka then how to reconstruct html file at consumer side in  kafka ?

This is how i am converting html files into Array[Byte]

```
def getByteArray(fileName: String): Array[Byte] =
 {
   val file: File = new File(fileName)
   val fileinputstream: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
   IOUtils.toByteArray(fileinputstream)
 }
```

suggest me solution which will give the file back at consumer side by applying that function. e.g.

```
def byteArrayToFile(data:Array[Byte]):String={
//suggest
}
```

Comment: Do the opposite of what you did on the client to get to the byte array format? This doesn't sound like it's specific to kafka.

Comment: @cricket_007 please provide some way , i am blocked

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: `new String(data, "UTF-8")`??

Comment: this is not working @cricket_007 and gives output like-[B@4e04a765

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert a byte array to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233355/convert-a-byte-array-to-string)

Comment: What you show looks like `data.toString`... There's only so many ways to get bytes to a String, and that's not it